# Dynamic table select based on another table value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a work table "sheet1" with columns "Article, article_1(1,2,3,4), database_id1". I have ten (or more) tables with database_id (table1, table2, table3...) with four columns :

table1: article_1, database_id1, Information, another_information
Table2: article_2, database_id2, information, another information

I need to make a query like `select article, information, another information WHERE article1=database_id1 FROM database_id(NUMBER)` some kind of dynamic table.

Comment: Life would be much simpler if you optimized data structure. Those ten or more tables should probably be 1 table with another field for a category.

Comment: The source table cannot be dynamic in query object. Would have to use VBA QueryDefs to modify query object.

Comment: Also, your query doesn't make sense because it SELECTs field `article` that is not in the ten tables. And FROM clause is always before WHERE clause.

Comment: I find the table structure unclear and would suggest an edit.:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It's about 2000 tables, with around 15-20gb, but single the bigger file is around 50mb, that's why i try to link the files separately in access. Indeed, i'm not very skilled in using access but in my mind it's more faster to select some information from three tables and around 60.000 lines each one, instead of selecting some information from one table with 180.000 lines. For The moment i work only with few tables which are under 2gb so this solution is ok for The moment (this few tables in bigger one)